# Delete elements from a vector in C++11 while iterating over it

Tags: c++, c++11

My applications requires to iterate over a vector and delete certain elements which doesnt satisfy the requirements. Which is the most correct way? I believe the following way is incorrect.Reason: I am getting segmentation fault.

```
std::vector<ObjectX> vec1;
//Fill in vec1
std::vector<ObjectX>::iterator itVec1 = vec1.begin();

for(;itVec1 != vec1.end(); ++itVec1) {
   if (Oracle(*itVec1)) vec1.erase(itVec1);
}
```

Comment: When you're using `erase`,  it invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase, including the end() iterator.

Comment: I usually iterate it in reverse order and use index access instead of vector iterator

Comment: I feel like the two most frequent C++ questions I see: how do I get numbers out of `std::string`s and why is my program segfaulting when invalidating my iterator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call

```
vec1.erase(itVec1);
```

you invalidate `itVec1`. After that, `++itVec1` is not right. It leads to undefined behavior. You need to change your code a little bit.

```
for( ; itVec1 != vec1.end(); ) {
   if (Oracle(*itVec1))
   {
      itVec1 = vec1.erase(itVec1);
   }
   else
   {
      ++itVec1;
   }
}
```

You can remove all the boiler plate code by using the [Erase-Remove Idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom):

```
vec1.erase(std::remove_if(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), Oracle), vec1.end());
```

Comment: this loop is anachronistic. teach him the right way - erase/remove_if.

Answer (score 0):

You could just put the correct items into a new vector.